# Query DBF Data Base in MatLab using JDBC under windows 7 x64

Tags: matlab, jdbc, database-connection, dbf

I want to know if is possible to query a DBF Data Base/File in a **DSN less** way using a JDBC driver in MatLab x64 under Windows7 x64.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The submited link talks about  using a ODBC Driver, not JDBC.

Comment: The first answer describes a DSN-less way to connect, but yes it does need the JDBC ODBC bridge and an ODBC driver. You didn't say you didn't want to use ODBC at all. The second answer seems to indicate there is yet another way.